# Is there an alternative for the phrase "Sorry about my English"?

Tags: usage, phrases

Is there an alternative for the phrase below?

> Sorry about my English.

I usually use this phrase at the end of my texts to show that I'm still learning English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sorry for my English* is quite acceptable.

Another possibility may be:

"*Please excuse my English*"

Comment: "*Pardon my English.*"